How to calculate the clockwise rotation (bearing) from 3 known coordinates and independent of the cartesian XY axes
Greetings Maths experts,
I come to you once more looking for mathematical assistance to help me solve another challenge in my CAD software.
Background Info:
I'm trying to write a VBA macro which will help me rotate specific elements to be parallel with the X-axis of the current view window. By default, a view window will have zero rotation around the Z-axis with elements drawn on the XY plane, however, I am building in the capability in the macro so that if a View Window is rotated around the Z-axis, this rotation is accounted for in the rotation calculation.
What I've done so far/Information I can provide or have calculated:
Here is an example with some test geometry:


The Global Coordinate System's (0,0) origin and orientation can be seen at the red & green XY
This particular View Window has been rotated 15° CCW and the grey dash-dot line is drawn parallel to the view's X-axis. This line itself isn't important, I've only added it to demonstrate the extents of the rotation from the global coordinate system.
The Blue dash-dot line isn't important, it is added only for context as it is drawn parallel to the Y-axis of the XY plane.
The white lines represent the lines between which that I am trying to calculate the clockwise rotation between i.e. the 105°
The coordinates at the end of the white lines can all be provided. The coordinate at the intersection of the white lines is always known, and the other two are calculated using a function I have written based upon these formulae from the book 'Essential Mathematics for Computer Graphics Fast' by John Vince

What I need assistance with:
As mentioned above, I am ultimately trying to calculate the clockwise angle (or bearing rotation) between the white lines. I have done this previously using the ATAN2 function, however, from my tests using these coordinates to provide the (y,x) inputs, the calculated angle is incorrect. I suspect this might be because the ATAN2 function works using the Cartesian X axis of the coordinate system, whereas, I need the calculated angle to be independent of the coordinate system's axes and calculated from the Y-axis of the View Window.
If you need further information, feel free to ask.
Thanks

It isn't, it's y,x. I've checked and can post a screenshot proving that is (y,x)

See this for the VBA IDE parameter info https://ibb.co/27JTdJC

I've never made mention of measuring from the X-axis. Indeed I am looking for a CW measurement but not from the y-axis (which would be to the coordinate system's Y-axis). I need the measurement to the Y-axis parallel to the view, which makes me think that the atan2 function isn't suitable for this situation.

If you know the coordinates $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ of two unit vectors, the cosine of their angle is given by their scalar product $ac+bd.$ The sine of their angle (to distinguish between the intervals $0°-180°$ and $180°-360°$, or otherwise said, to resolve the ambiguity of the sign of the angle) is the determinant $ad-bc.$ If you don't want your code to be muddled with conditional statements, you can apply atan2 to those two numbers.

Thanks for the reply. I've attempted to follow what you've said but have run into some difficulty. I can calculate the create 2 vectors from the 3No. coordinates, normalise them to create unit vectors, and then calculate the Dot Product. Unfortunately, there isn't a built-in function in VBA for Inverse Cosine or Inverse Sine so you have to use derived formulae instead link.

In a test case, I calculate a Dot Product of -0.470 and when I use that with the derived formula for Inverse Cosine: Arccos(X) = Atn(-X / Sqr(-X * X + 1)) + 2 * Atn(1) , it gives a value of 2.10357... whereas if you use cos−1(0.470) with the windows calculator, it returns 118.0343... Safe to say I'm completely confused at the difference.

That should read cos−1(-0.470)

Windows works in degrees, VBA uses radians. If you multiply $2.1$ by $180/\pi$ you get the same result (approximately).

Thanks. Yes, I forgot that. I can see that works and that that it is the smaller of the 2 angles which is being reported instead of the desired clockwise angle. What steps do you advise I now use to ensure calculation of the this? I didn't follow your suggestion when you mentioned using the Sin of the angle etc...

Either use an if/then statement to replace the angle with its positive opposite whenever the 'sine' determinant is negative (i.e., subtract the angle from a full circle); or use the atan2 function with the cosine and the sine as values for $x$ and $y,$ respectively. In the latter case you can even afford not to normalise the original $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ anymore as the atan2 function will give the same result when multiplying $x$ and $y$ by a positive constant.
